# Sniffing a LIN Network in LAB

Tags: sensors

I am posed with a situation where I have a LIN sensor but without any documentation or literature on the same. I am new to LIN protocol and understand that it is a request and response protocol. Now I want to read all the data that the LIN sensor can generate to check if I can decipher the hex data and make sense out of it.

All I have is the sensor and a few Arduino and ESP boards using which we implemented CAN protocol.
We are exploring a LIN-To-CAN converter but again we need to configure the converter with the addresses to read from.

Is this possible using any tool or techniques? If yes, kindly let me know and point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you start by reading the [Wikipedia page on LIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Interconnect_Network), which tells you a lot about LIN? The full specs are also available from ISO (ISO 17987 parts 1 to 8), at a cost, though. From what I understand LIN uses a UART-based serial bus, so it's probably a lot easier to connect your sensor directly to an UART on your Arduino or ESP than going through CAN.

Comment: You’ll probably need some level shifters though as LIN devices use very different voltages from the common 3.3 or 5V commonly found. See also https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla383a/slla383a.pdf for some additional info.

Comment: Hi jcaron, thanks for the comments. I do understand that it uses a serial bus. But my major question is, how do I query the data without knowing the LIN address map. Is there a way to get the messages broadcasted like how CAN broadcasts the messages OR MODBUS would query all the devices if the id is set to 0. I was looking for something like that. Hope that makes sense and do correct me if i am missing something.

Comment: Subbu, its been nine months. Were you able to do something about this ? Let the community know any learnings you may have experienced in this area.